# Ambiguous Overloaded method call resolved

Tags: java, overloading

When I call, `call('a');` it output "char" and it is fine because char primitive type will take first priority over boxing it to Character.

```
static void call(char i){
    System.out.println("char");
}

static void call(Character i){
    System.out.println("Character");
}
```

How is call to `call('a', 'a');` is ambiguous?

```
static void call(char i, Character j){
    System.out.println("char");
}

static void call(Character i, Character j){
    System.out.println("Character");
}
```

What I am thinking is for second parameter compiler has to go for Boxing and for first parameter perfect match is char primitive type, so call to `call('a','a');` can be resolved to `call(char i, Character j)` method.

Obviously I am understanding it wrong, someone please explain this.

Some links where particular this kind of example is explained will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is call to `call('a', 'a');` is ambiguous?

Because in order for the `(char i, Character j)` overload to be applicable, the rules around boxing are brought into play - and at that point *both* calls are applicable. This is the second phase of determining the method signature [(JLS 15.12.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
> 2. The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.

So in phase 2, both methods are applicable, but the rules for determining the most specific method ([JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) don't make either of the calls more specific than each other. It's not a matter of "unboxed is more specific than boxed" - it's a matter of "can I resolve this without any boxing" before "can I resolve this with boxing".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, out of 3 JLS rules, by applying first rule where no boxing and unboxing is considered, call to call(char i, Character j) is not clear as first parameter can be resolved but second parameter requires boxing and it is out of scope of 1st rule and control passes to 2nd rule, where boxing and unboxing is considered, so in this case both call(char i, Character j)  and call(Character i, Character j) are applicable as is unable to resolve that is why it is giving compile error? please confirm whether my understanding is correct. Thanks.

Comment: my question is, in 2nd rule does it simply checks all method combination and call is mapped to many methods that is why it is giving error? I was thinking that in 2nd rule it might be checking that first parameter of call(char i, Character j) is exact match and for second parameter call is resolved using Boxing,

Comment: @Jayesh: Yes, it's going on to phase 2, and at that point neither method is more specific than the other. Note that "more specific" doesn't look at the actual call - either one method is more specific than the other, or it isn't. In this case, neither is more specific than the other.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the [JLS 15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

For your first `call` method with `char` and `Character` the compiler needs only the first phase in order to know which method to call. And in the first phase it's not mixing boxed and primitive types:

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

However, in your calls with 2 arguments (`char` and `Character`, and `Character` and `Character`) the compiler needs to get to the **second** phase trying to distinguish between them, and at that specific point both method are valid:

> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation.

Comment: The compiler doesn't get to the third phase, because both are applicable in the second phase. "The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase."